# Why we check EditText not equal to null in OnCreate method

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

**Let me clarify my question**
OnCreate method is used to initialize view and flatten the layout , so I am thinking that if onCreate method is running before everything means my EditText field is empty means null so how this condition is working. But it working fine it means I am understanding something incorrectly.
Please tell me what I am missing.

*code snippet is taken from google codelabs where we are providing phone no. in editText and by clicking send button in device inbuilt keyboard we launch phone application to dial given number.*

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText_main);
if (editText != null) {
   editText.setOnEditorActionListener
                         (new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    return false;
                }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code...

calling `findViewById(R.id.editText_main);` can return null if a view with id "editText_main" was not found on the referenced xml layout of your activity, and when you call `editText.setOnEditorActionListener` in such scenario a [NullPointerException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException) will be thrown causing your app to crash.

So if you're sure there will always be an id "editText_main" in your referenced layout then the "if condition" is useless. However if there is a possibility of not having a view with id "editText_main" assuming you set different layout based on some conditions then its important to check for nullity on your editText.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   if(a == b){
       // Layout containing view with id "editText_main"
       setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity_1);
   }
   else if(a == c){
       // Layout without "editText_main"
       setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity_2);
   }
   else{
       // Layout without "editText_main"
       setContentView(R.layout.sample_activity_3);
   }

   EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText_main);
   // editText will be null if the referenced layout is not sample_activity_1
   // which would cause a NullPointerException
   editText.setOnEditorActionListener
                     (new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
   });
}
```

Comment: I understand it like this -> we want to get text from an editText which in sample_activity_1, but which layout we have right now is depend on some condition, so now it is necessary to check editText is present in the current layout or not.

Comment: Am I right ????

Comment: @Explosive yes you're right. It's necessary to check if editText is present in the current layout or not when you sent layout dynamically.

Comment: @Explosive Don't forget to mark as accepted answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Yes, giddy I tried your example and it really throw Null Pointer Exception, if the layout is not as assumed, so I am concluding that your answer is right.

Comment: Can you please up-vote my question :)

Answer (score 0):

The null check prevents a null pointer exception if you try to access the editText before the layout is inflated. But if you're setting this variable in the onCreate method after the call to inflate the layout then the editText shouldn't be null. The text property may be (since you haven't typed anything yet) but the component itself shouldn't be null.